# To access command line in cPanel, is there a software should be installed?

Tags: command-line, cpanel

What is the place in cPanel that allows me to run a script?

For example: where should I go in cPanel to run `gem -v/--version`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do that you need `"SSH Access"`

Confirm with your hosting provider whether you has `"SSH Access"`

If not, you can't do that

If yes, you can `ssh` your account with your `login details` by using some `ssh s/w`

I recommend `Putty` to `"SSH"`

You can get an idea on how to ssh by going through the following link

> http://support.hostgator.com/articles/hosting-guide/lets-get-started/how-do-i-get-and-use-ssh-access

However, this link is by hostgator you can adopt it to other hosting too

Hope this answers your question .Good luck :-)

Comment: @Shood Thanks and happy that you got a solution